# What language and how to test script that will run in android terminal app

Tags: linux, windows, script, android, bash-scripting

I want to write a script that can run in a terminal app on an android device. I have basic questions about getting started.

*Background:* I have a Windows batch file that (basically) pulls folders from an android tablet, replaces images in each folder with images on the pc, then pushes the folders back. I now want to do this with a script that will run in a terminal or some other script-running app on my tablet. (It will replace the images in the folders with images already on the device.)

I just need to know how to get started:

- Do I use bash or can I/should I use some other scripting language, or just "plain" linux?
- How do I test this script?

I first thought I'd write a few commands in Notepad++, save as .sh file, manually copy script file to tablet and run it, but that seems cumbersome.
Is there a way to test on my usb-connected tablet from (something like) a "linux script console" on Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb` do run simple commands on your phone. Just type in `adb shell` and you get a shell. You might use `adb push <source> <destination>` to push your script to the device too. Maybe the adb help provides more info there could be an option to run scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own Android script, which moved some files to a folder automatically. What I did was:

- Write your script starting with `#!/system/bin/sh`. I used simple bash commands.
- Save your script **without any file extension**. Your phone will automatically know it's a shell script.
- Connect your phone to USB and type the following in a cmd: `adb push [path-to-file] [path-to-save]` or just drag and drop into your preferred folder.
- It may happen that your phone doesn't like your non-extension file. If this happens, add a .sh to your script file and try again. Download an Android file manager (Root Browser should do OK) and remove the extension. (I had some problems here, I can try it for you if you aren't successful.)
- Download Terminal Emulator from Play Store and type the following:

  ```
  su
  ```

  chmod 755 [path-to-script]

  ```
  ./[script]
  ```
- If all works properly, that should be fine.